# 2 models in one form - how to save the data to respective tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, fields-for

I have this action for updating data:

```
  def edit
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    if @project.team
      @team = Team.find(@project.id)
    else
      @team = Team.new
    end
  end
```

Form:

```
= form_for @project do |f|
  ...
  = f.fields_for @team do |t|
  #if I use following: = f.fields_for :team do |t|, then the form inputs in this form are not displayed
    ...
  end

end
```

Models:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :team
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :team
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end
```

When I try to send the form, I get following error message

```
Team(#2501295380) expected, got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#2157764620)
```

I found similar posts here on SO, but no one helped me to solved this issue, that's why I'll be very grateful for every advice.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is solving my issue:

```
  def edit
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    unless @project.team.nil?
      @project.team
    else
      @project.build_team
    end  
  end
```

Comment: remove the unless line and `@project.team` no need for that only condition you can have is `@project.build_team if @project.team.nil?`